# Windows Service C# to Upload Files Using Google Drive API Not Working After Installing

Tags: windows, service, visual-studio-2013, google-drive-api

Following is the code for uploading to the drive folder. This will be called by a thread in the windows service. Everything is working fine when run in the debug mode. But once I install it using visual studio installer it's not really working. When I try to debug it using a event log file it's breaking as soon as the function is called.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;


namespace RedHillsServiceV1._0
{
    class AjCloudConnect
    {
        public void cloudStart()
        {

            try
            { 
            UserCredential credential =                     GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "181014074404-                  
                    ClientSecret = "3vgzlLoEF_",
                },
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "PseudoGPService",
        });

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        body.Description = "log file";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
        Console.WriteLine("----File id: " + file.Id+" has been successfully uploaded at"+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")+"-----");
        //Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
        //Console.ReadLine();
       }
        catch(Exception clEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clEx.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

}

Also this is the code for the thread in the service:

```
    public void callUpThreadStart()
    {
        try
        { 
        //Thread.Sleep(4500000);
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            //Thread.Sleep(900000);
            Console.WriteLine("----Starting Upload Thread----");
            //Service1 UpSer = new Service1(); 
            //Console.WriteLine(isLogging);
            int d;
            if (InternetGetConnectedState(out d, 0))
            {
                if (new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt").Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("----The File is Empty----");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("----Internet Connection Detected----");

                    if (isLogging)
                    {
                        isLogging = false;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);

                    AjCloudConnect ajcc = new AjCloudConnect();
                    ajcc.cloudStart();
                    flag = 0;
                    clearText();
                    isLogging = true;

                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----No Internet Connection Detected----");

                flag = 1;
            }

        }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generic Exception", e);
            upThreadRestart();

        }


    }
```

Finally, I have created service as local system, when run in debug mode the program will ask for authentication using browser for first time its not doing so when run in installed. Please kindly help, I am sorry if I am missing to provide any information.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't saving the authentication. So what makes you think it wouldn't ask for authentication again? Really I don't think a windows service can ask for authentication every time it starts it kind of defeats the purpose of having a windows service doesn't it? Might want to start by adding FileDataStore or some other implementation of iDataStore to your initial request to save the authentication.

Example using FileDataStore:

```
UserCredential credential =                     GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "181014074404-                  
                    ClientSecret = "3vgzlLoEF_",
                },
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
            CancellationToken.None
            , new FileDataStore("Daimto.Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

Helpful links

1. Google Drive .net sample project: [GitHub](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive)
2. Google Drive .net Upload tutorial: [Google drive API with C# .net - upload](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/)

Comment: Still doesn't solve my issue. Also not adding a new filedatastore will only mean the default filedatastore will be used. Further the tutorial from google devs(https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs) doesn't reflect any filedatastore implementation. Kindly suggest me some way. Thanks.

Comment: Actually not adding filedatastore will mean that your authentication is not saved any place and it will ask again every time.   FileDataStore is the default excepted method, again it saves to %appdata% does your service have access to write there?   Again a windows server probably cant popup requesting authentication so your code wont work, without you saving the initial authentication from a user at some point.

Comment: official documentation that incudes filedatastore https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: Small correction here: If you don't use a data store (e.g. using http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.1/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.html#a95045cb55eeb08fadd27b33e0193327c) the library creates a FileDataStore for you, as you can find out in the implementation: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs#121

Comment: Exactly peeleyal, the issue wasn't about FileDataStore that was my point for which I got -1 to the question. I had to change my architecture because of the issue and uploading using sftp.